# How to access UrlHelper.Action or similar from within Global asax

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

*I am trying to prepare a 301 redirect for a typo I made 'recieved'*

I am struggling to find a way of getting the url from the action and controller names.

I am aware of UrlHelper.Action but it does not exist within Global.asax. How do I gain access to this method?:

```
// Add permanent redirection for retired pages (Application_BeginRequest())
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath.ToLower().StartsWith("/blah/listrecieved"))    
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(/*Need url generated from action and controller*/);
}
```

Alternatively I have created a route, if that's how I should be getting the string, this is also fine but I am unsure of how:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "blah-list-received",
    url: "blah/list-received",
    defaults: new { controller = "Blah", action = "ListReceived" }
);
```

for example, it might look like this:

```
// Add permanent redirection for retired pages
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath.ToLower().StartsWith("/blah/listrecieved"))    
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(routes.GetUrl( "blah-list-received" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to construct the `UrlHelper` yourself:

```
var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, RouteTable.Routes)
             .Action("YourAction",
                     "YourController",
                     new { paramName = paramValue });
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: I think you have some typo on that first line you have provided. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Same issue, you have too many brackets there :D Thank you though, really appreciate your help... Just checking if it works now!

Comment: This explains that the route data parameter must not be null: `Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: routeData`

Comment: Thanks man, now I've got to sort out the context not being available here. Any ideas on how the 301 should actually be working?

Comment: Why isn't it available? In which method of your `Global.asax` you're calling it?

Comment: ahahah evidently the wrong one, I had in application_start, and now moved to Application_BeginRequest().. it works. thanks man!